# Programmatically Delete one Files at a time in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress custom file uploader in my custom theme and now I need to be able to delete each file when a button is clicked.
I have this so far:

```
 <?php

    $attachments = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'post_status' => null,
        )
    );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
     
       
                            $file_link = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, "full");
                            $file_img = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID);
    
                            $file_title = get_the_title($attachment->ID);
                            $size_media = filesize(get_attached_file($attachment->ID));
    
                            $total_size = ($size_media) / 1000;
    
    
                        ?>

                                <div>
    
                                    <a href="http:<?php echo $file_link; ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <div>
                                            <?php if (strpos($file_link, '.png') !== false || strpos($file_link, '.jpg') !== false || strpos($file_link, '.gif') !== false || strpos($file_link, '.tif') !== false ) {
                                                echo '<span class="material-icons">insert_photo</span>';
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<span class="material-icons">description</span>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="http:<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, "full");  ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <p><?php echo $file_title; ?></p>
                                    </a>
                                    <p>Size: <?php echo $total_size; ?>KB</p>
                                    <a href="<?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID ); ?>">Delete</a>
                                </div>

                        <?php } ?>
    
    
    }
```

What is happening is that when the Delete link is pressed ALL the files are deleted. I don't want that. I need only that one file where the link was pressed to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a wrong assumption about php-functions included in html. What php does is, it outputs some html. In your case what you are doing is:

```
<a href="<?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID ); ?>">Delete</a>
```

This tells Wordpress to delete the attachment immediately. It then returns nothing, so you html will look like this:

```
<a href="">Delete</a>
```

What you need is a javascript function that does an ajax request to tell the server-side php to delete a specific attachment. You can call this in the html:

```
<a href="deleteFile(<?php echo $attachment->ID ?>);">Delete</a>
```

This will result in the following html:

```
<a onclick="deleteFile(30);">Delete</a>
```

Now you can go and write a javascript function called `deleteFile` and takes the attachment id as argument. It should send the id to the server and call `wp_delete_attachment( $_GET['id'] )`.